# Yii save uploaded file to base64 string

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to save an uploaded photo in my database using base64 but I can't get the data:

Form:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm',
            array(
                    'id' => 'upload-form',
                    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
                    'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
            ));?>
<?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'attachment');?>
```

Controller:

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['Post'];
                    //gives me the filename
        $model->attachment=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'attachment');
```

How do I get the contents so I can encode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['Post'];

//gives me the filename
$tmpfile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'attachment');

$tmpfile_contents = file_get_contents( $tmpfile->tempName );

$model->attachment = base64_encode($tmpfile_contents);
```

Comment: It fits but one more thing. If I want to fill the input with the file path on update what should I do? store the path also?

Comment: you will have to store the uploaded file on the file system, using "save" method of your "CUploadedFile" instance. check out http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile#tempName-detail for available methods and properties...